# ¿Como mostrar columnas específicas de una base de datos en un datagridview c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datagridview

Quiero llenar un `DataGridView` con columnas especificas de una tabla base de datos mediante consulta `select * from`:

ejemplo de la tabla

tabla usuario

```
id = "12"

nombre = "David"

edad = "21"
```

Solo quiero mostrar las columnas id y nombre en mi `DataGridView`.

Comment: No logro entender bien qué quieres hacer, pero para mostrar solo unas columnas específicas puedes usar "select id, nombre edad from usuarios"

Comment: Debes agregar en la pregunta el código que tengas hecho.

Comment: "select id, nombre edad from usuarios", gracias es lo deseaba resolver, no pensé que fuese algo tan sencillo.

Comment: puedes elegir de cualquier forma un select * from tabla, y en el gridview decirle que columna vas a hacer el render mendiante un databound, de esa forma puedes reutilizar tus consultas y dibujar lo que te interese saber.

Answer (score 0):

Si defines las columnas en tiempo de diseño en el datagridview puedes luego indicar el `DataPropertyName` de cada columna indicando cual es el campo de la query con el que mapea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aunque la query defina varios campos en el grid solo se veras los que definas en el diseño

Por supuesto asigna la propiedad `AutoGenerateColumns` en false

Comment: Gracias, por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podés hacer es por un lado no hacer un SELECT * FROM TABLA y cambiarlo por SELECT ID, NOMBRE FROM TABLA.
Esa es la más fácil. 
Si no te queda otra que partir de un Select * lo que podés hacer, en tiempo de ejecución, es ocultar las columas luego de cargada

Sería 
dgv.Columns("edad").Visible = False

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

es importante tener en cuenta que si la consulta hecha en BD trae los tres datos, en las propiedades del datagridview la propiedad autogeneratedcoloumns este en false para de esta forma elegir solo las dos colunmas neesaria, pero es mucho mejor desde la consulta de la BD que se consulten solo las dos columnas necesarias, para tu caso la columna ID y Nombre